# no result input found error, even with SkipValidation

Tags: validation, struts2

I have an **validate()** method and two execute methods in my action class, one for preparing the form and the other for submission and redirection to another page. My Action class is as follows:

```
    @SkipValidation
    public String execute()
    {
        return "success";
    }

    public String execute2()
    {
       return "success";
    }
```

And my struts.xml is as follows:

```
        <action name="EmpForm" class="actions.EmployeeAction">
             <result>/EmployeeForm.jsp</result> 
        </action>

        <action name="EmployeeDetails" class="actions.EmployeeAction" method="execute2">
            <result>/EmpDetails.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/EmployeeForm.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

when the EmpForm action is called, I get an error saying `No result defined for action actions.EmployeeAction and result input`

Why is that even though I have a @SkipValidation, it still is demanding a `<result name="input">`? Also, even if I give such a result, I am getting the same error. Any pointers on what the issue is?

---

The full error stack trace is as follows:

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:345)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:44)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:161)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.intercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:115)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:507)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Basically it is entering the validate() method even though it is not supposed to as the annotation is present.

Comment: is this the error or can you show the complete stack-trace? additionally this is because you have some validation either as a validate() method or standard validator framework which is sending back input result type, additional doubt can be some thing failingin between and sending back the result

Comment: Hi Umesh. Yes, I do have a null field validation inside the validate() and the validation is failing on form load. But should that not be skipped, as I have the annotation?

Comment: can you show the error conssole output.Please update your post

Comment: Could be a type conversion problem.

Comment: @DeepakMahalingam: agree with Dave, can you just remove validate method and see if the problem still there or not?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. If I remove the validate() then no error is shown. But my question is, since I have used the @SkipValidation method, why is the validate method being called at all? Should it not be called only on form submission and when the execute2() is invoked? And again, if I have the validate() then if error occurs then it navigates back to the form as expected.